# What is exactly the difference between Huggingface, MLserver and seldon core?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, huggingface

Kind of a newbie to practical ML development.

As far as I can understand, huggingface provides packaged, ready to deploy, pre trained ML models, whereas MLserver and seldon core are used to actually deploy it on servers. However, I'm still unsure of what it is they do exactly, can anyone help?